# Append data-slb-group="slb"

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a set of several images, I want to use append, but I'm not getting

```
        <a href="image1.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" data-slb-internal="0" 
data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image1.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image1.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>   
        <a href="image2.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" 
data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image2.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image2.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>
        <a href="image3.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253"
 data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image3.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image3.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>

    <div class="images"></div>
```

this code works

```
$('.size-medium').appendTo('.images');
```

but within the div images only the images appear, the `<a>` links do not appear

I tried the code below and several other attempts but did not get the result

```
  $('a data-slb-group').appendTo('.images');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a correct selector because you're looking for a tag called `<a data-slb-group>`

```
 $('a data-slb-group').appendTo('.images');
```

You can access to atributes by using **attr function**  `$(element).attr('atributeName')`

**Here the solution:**

You could do that by capsuling all you want to take into a div like:

```
<div id='capsule'>
        <a href="image1.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" data-slb-internal="0" 
data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image1.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image1.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>   
        <a href="image2.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" 
data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image2.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image2.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>
        <a href="image3.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253"
 data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image3.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image3.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>
</div>
<div class="images"></div>
```

And then just use something like this:

```
var html = document.getElementById('capsule').innerHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName('images')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
```

`innerHTML` **select all the HTML inside that div**. There is a JQuery function called **html()** that do exactly the same thing:

Look: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, but I have many pages in wordpress, I can not go into each of the pages and put the `<div id='capsule'>` manually

Comment: I'm gonna try to make a complex selector and then select exactly those images without using that div, wait

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait.